# TeamCity fails to run "npm install" on WindowsServer

Tags: node.js, npm, continuous-integration, teamcity

I have a build step in TeamCity which is executing the

```
npm install
```

This is a Node.js project.

It's failing with the errors:

> [10:49:37]npm ERR! git clone
>   --template=C:\npm-cache_git-remotes_templates --mirror git://github.com/ifandelse/riveter.git
>   C:\npm-cache_git-remotes\git-github-com-ifandelse-riveter-git-0cffebb92117c88543cb4359fb9fd69c2d65dd22-e68db054c0bd30b07ce1f9879b4f866f:
>   Cloning into bare repository
>   'C:\npm-cache_git-remotes\git-github-com-ifandelse-riveter-git-0cffebb92117c88543cb4359fb9fd69c2d65dd22-e68db054c0bd30b07ce1f9879b4f866f'...
>   [10:49:37]npm ERR! git clone
>   --template=C:\npm-cache_git-remotes_templates --mirror git://github.com/ifandelse/riveter.git
>   C:\npm-cache_git-remotes\git-github-com-ifandelse-riveter-git-0cffebb92117c88543cb4359fb9fd69c2d65dd22-e68db054c0bd30b07ce1f9879b4f866f:
>   fatal: unable to connect to github.com: [10:49:37]npm ERR! git clone
>   --template=C:\npm-cache_git-remotes_templates --mirror git://github.com/ifandelse/riveter.git
>   C:\npm-cache_git-remotes\git-github-com-ifandelse-riveter-git-0cffebb92117c88543cb4359fb9fd69c2d65dd22-e68db054c0bd30b07ce1f9879b4f866f:
>   github.com[0: 192.30.252.129]: errno=No error [10:50:09]npm ERR!
>   Windows_NT 6.1.7601 [10:50:09]npm ERR! argv "C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install"
>   "--msvs_version=2012" [10:50:09]npm ERR! node v0.10.33 [10:50:09]npm
>   ERR! npm  v3.3.10 [10:50:09]npm ERR! code 128 [10:50:09] [10:50:09]npm
>   ERR! Command failed: Cloning into bare repository
>   'C:\npm-cache_git-remotes\git-github-com-ifandelse-riveter-git-0cffebb92117c88543cb4359fb9fd69c2d65dd22-e68db054c0bd30b07ce1f9879b4f866f'...
>   [10:50:09]npm ERR! fatal: unable to connect to github.com:
>   [10:50:09]npm ERR! github.com[0: 192.30.252.129]: errno=No error
>   [10:50:09]npm ERR!  [10:50:09]npm ERR!  [10:50:09]npm ERR! 
>   [10:50:09]npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
>   [10:50:09]npm ERR!     https://github.com/npm/npm/issues;

I can run **npm install** fine from the command line. This requires to "run as Administrator" thought.

I've tried to add Administrator role to the TeamCityAgent user.

I'm pretty sure something is wrong with the permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe because you can't connect to github through ssh or git protocol (maybe because of a firewall or other).
Try to force git to clone via https :

```
git config --global url."https://github.com/".insteadOf git@github.com:
git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://
```